# VBA Searching for P/N's in two Sheets and copying data

Tags: git, vba, excel, macros

this is my very first VBA program and post here so take it easy :D.
I am a summer intern working in the AeroSpace department, our project curently involves headvy satellite production and I am in charge of delivering the end item data package to our customer. 
One of these deliverables includes something called an As Design As Build.
In essence, I've made a macro that searches P/N's in one sheet to another sheet. Both are controller by a counter, x is the counter for the Bom sheet and y is the counter for the Master sheet. if the P/N's are equal it copies some cells from the BOM to the Master sheet. 
Here the BOM is the ever changing sheet and the Master is what each vehicle should have one it.
Missing items are my problem here. I've coded it so missing items in the BOM just get skipped in the Master leaving a blank. However, if there is an item on the BOM that is not on the master it searches all of the rows, hits the end, and then breaks. I have tried adding this to counter it but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
    Else
    y = y + 1
    If (y = FinalRow) Then
    x = x + 1
```

I'm pretty much trying to bump the x value or move down a row on the Bom sheet if the y value has reached the end of the master sheet to continue the loop.
Any help/criticism would be great!
Sub ADAB()
'Need Master and Bom worksheet

```
Dim dataFile As String
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim iFound As Integer
Dim BomValue As String
Dim MasterValue As String

'Set variables
Workbooks("ADAB Tool.xlsm").Activate
dataFile = Cells(1, 1).Value
Set WB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=dataFile, ReadOnly:=False)
'Open workbook from path

    Worksheets("Master").Activate
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    y = 2
    x = 2
Do While (y <= FinalRow)
    Workbooks("ADAB1.xlsx").Activate
    Worksheets("Bom").Activate
    BomValue = Worksheets("Bom").Cells((x), 1).Value
        MasterValue = Worksheets("Master").Cells((y), 1).Value
        iFound = 0
        If (BomValue = MasterValue) Then
            Worksheets("Master").Activate
            Worksheets("Bom").Activate
            Dim Range As Range
            Set Range = Worksheets("Bom").Range(Cells(x, 1), Cells(x, 4))
            Worksheets("Master").Activate
            Worksheets("Master").Range(Cells(y, 3), Cells(y, 6)) = Range.Value
            iFound = 1
            x = x + 1
            y = y + 1
        Else
            y = y + 1
            If (y = FinalRow) Then
            x = x + 1
        End If
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: When it breaks, does it throw an error? Also, just to point out, you need to add the worksheet before `Cells()` just like you did with `Range()`, otherwise you can get some unexpected results.

Comment: It doesn't give any error, but the whole searching/copying process stops. I'll add the worksheets before the cells thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see the need to keep "activating" your sheets.  you should probably just create objects...it will make your life easier

```
dim master as worksheet
set master = thisworksbook.worksheets("master")
```

Then you can refer to it only as "master" from then on.

```
master.cells(x,1) = foo
```

As for your questions, I might consider making an array of P/Ns, then looping through the Master and looking for matches...seems like you are trying to accomplish too much for one little loop!  Its hard to tell from your description though, just my two cents!

Comment: Thanks for the objects tip that'll come in handy. Still trying to learn the basics so I threw in a lot of the activates just to be safe. So instead of searching the master use the master and search the BOM? I'll have to see if that is feasible for the project, each vehicle is slightly different in the items that it has on.

Answer (score 0):

After a little bit of tweaking I was able to fix my problem. By assigning z = y before y increments z acts as y = y-1 in the ElseIf statement.

```
    If (BomValue = MasterValue) Then
        Worksheets("Master").Activate
        Worksheets("Bom").Activate
        Dim Range As Range
        Set Range = Worksheets("Bom").Range(Cells(x, 1), Cells(x, 4))
        Worksheets("Master").Activate
        Worksheets("Master").Range(Cells(y, 3), Cells(y, 6)) = Range.Value
        iFound = 1
        z = y
        x = x + 1
        y = y + 1
    ElseIf (y >= FinalRow And x < FinalRowBom) Then
        x = x + 1
        y = z
    Else
        y = y + 1
    End If
Loop
```

This was able to loop through the entire document and wasn't caught up on any items.
Thanks for all your comments!